# Загрузка приложения в Windows Phone Store

Tags: c#, sql, .net, windows-phone-8, microsoft-store

В общем, решил сюда обратиться, потому что никто больше не может помочь в этом. Создаю приложение под Windows Phone. Разрабатывал его на эмуляторе, параллельно тестируя на своем личном телефоне. Через Visual Studio 2013 все деплоил. Когда настало время выкладывать в Windows Store, столкнулся с такой проблемой: чтобы загрузить в WS, нужно сначала скомпилировать в файл типа appx или appxbundle. Проверку сертификатов прошел. Проблема в том, что при скачивании приложения из маркета оно просто не запускается. Крашится на самом начале. При запуске лого.

В эмуляторе проблем нет, и все хорошо. А в скомпилированном файле беда. Как решить проблему, ребята?

**Обновление**

Только что попробовал установить дефолтное приложение в windows store. Заработало. Возможна ли проблема в компиляции библиотек? (Использую БД SQLite)

Comment: В общем, как оказалась проблема скорее всего в вызове асинхронных тасков. В мэйн меню была асинхронная функция. Когда ее убрал начало загружаться главное меню. Но остальные не работали. Может быть я как то не правильно асинхронные таски создаю? Как и где их создавать?

Comment: А как вы создаёте? Дайте код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблему решил. Только так я и не понял в чем она заключалась. Проблема была в том что я ранее создавал базу данных такой командой `SQliteConnections("db.db");`
Она создавалась и на эмуляторе и на телефоне. При загрузке с MarketPlace валилась ошибка из за этого. Оно не могло создать базу данных таким путем. Пришлось создавать такой строкой:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.db");
SqliteConnection(dbPath);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что приложениям из маркета запрещён произвольный доступ к файловой системе, разрешён только в свою песочницу.